# How to get roughly the whole country on the screen with zoom with 'google-map-react'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-map-react

basically I have this so far:

```
 <GoogleMapReact
   {...otherStuff}
   defaultZoom={3.5}
   defaultCenter={{
      lat: 59,
      lng: 26,
   }}
  />
```

this is great and works for some countries. but when I put in different `lat/lng` then the zoom is completely wrong for other countries.

I was wondering if there was anything clever I could do that would adjust the zoom so that basically most of that country is on screen. I'm not too fussy, I don't mind seeing parts of others but it would be good if the main country was focussed in the center. is there anything simple to solve this?

Comment: @Vepthy yes perfect, many thanks

Comment: No problem. Please, next time - try to find if there is already answer to your/similar question so we don't make duplicates and overcrowd the SO. Have a great day!

Comment: yeh apologies I found it hard to google the right thing :D ! you too

Comment: No problem mate! Enjoy your coding (:

Comment: @Vepthy hey man, not sure whether to open a new question but this hasn't worked so well for me. the countries are still not displaying as I'd like them too

Comment: Have you checked if you've did everything correctly? What errors does it give you?

Comment: no errors but it just isn't zooming in as much as I hoped. like for australia it's in the centre but nowhere near zoomed in that much.

Comment: Edit your question with what you've done and what is the output (maybe add JSfiddle)